# OpenGL rendering white texture bug

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, render-to-texture, spine

I use OpenGL and SDL2 to render spine animations. In a specific z-order this animations are disposed like white blocks. All texture get white. I guess this error is in OpenGL draw code.

```
glPushMatrix();

float texw=0, texh=0;
if (texture) {
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    if (SDL_GL_BindTexture(texture, &texw, &texh) != 0)
        printf("WTF\n");
}

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColor4f(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);


glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvs);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// if (num_vertices > 0) {
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
// glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);


if (texture) {
    SDL_GL_UnbindTexture(texture);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glPopMatrix();
```

This is my code, some one see something wrong in this code ?
Why i'm getting white textures ?
[image]

Comment: What are those `SDL_GL_BindTexture()`/`SDL_GL_UnbindTexture()` calls (which take `SDL_Texture`s, not `GLuint`s) doing in there?  Assuming `texture` is a `GLuint` like `glGenTextures()` requires, how'd that even *compile*?  Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Two-dimensional texturing has to be enabled by [`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml) and can be disabled by `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.
If texturing is enables then the texture wich is currently bound when the geometry is drawn  is wrapped on the geometry.

If texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).
This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

```cpp
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Note that all of this only applies in immediate mode if you are not using a shader program.

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76,
I tried to use your tip, but nothing has changed. The white blocks are still on the screen
:(

Comment: @JonasForte So there is another bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Do you think the bug isn't in this code ?

Comment: @JonasForte If texturing is enabled, the the quads can't be white, except the texture itself is white.